# JTable Swing: I cannot resize column by dragging cursor in header

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader

I cannot resize the column width by moving the cursor between header columns and drag the divider, despite of that I have set `setResizingAllowed()` to `true`.

```
tbResumen = new JTable();
tbResumen.setEnabled(false);

tbResumen.setRowHeight(20);
tbResumen.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Table.selectionBackground"));
tbResumen.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
tbResumen.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
tbResumen.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
tbResumen.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new RenderTablaInfo());
tbResumen.setOpaque(false);

tbResumen.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
tbResumen.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
tbResumen.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);

tbResumen.setSize(new Dimension(840, 450));
tbResumen.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(840, 450));

tbResumen.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

tbResumen.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] {{ label1, label2, label3, label4} },
new String[] { "foo", "bar", "foobar", "barfoo" }));

final JTableHeader headerResumen = new JTableHeader();
headerResumen.setReorderingAllowed(false); 
headerResumen.setResizingAllowed(true);
headerResumen.setColumnModel(tbResumen.getColumnModel());

headerResumen.setTable(tbResumen);
tbResumen.setTableHeader(headerResumen);
```

If someone needs more code to clarify the situation I'll add them soon. Thanks.

Comment: *"Any idea?"* For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Question edited after reading the link. If any idea after that...thanks.

Comment: You apparently did not understand the link, given that uncompilable code snippet is possibly M, but not C, V or an E of the problem. Note that a proper MCVE might be 150 LOC if it is all truly needed to make a complete, compilable and runnable example. A good test for an MCVE is as follow. Paste the 'MCVE' in a new project in your IDE. Compile it cleanly, run it to see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure your header is the one you are about to configure.

So, with:

```
JTableHeader headerResumen = tbResumen.getTableHeader();
headerResumen.setResizingAllowed(true);
```

I just create another header with the same `model` of my table and do config there, not realizing that **the new header I created is not that of my table**. I must call `table.getTableHeader()` to get the header I want and the config can work. Sorry for the stupidity.

2. Make sure you have set the cursor to be default cursor when hovering onto the edges between the columns in this table, so you can see it becomes a two-headed arrow and you are aware of that they are adjustable.

   `tbResumen.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(CURSOR_DEFAULT));`

If you set it to `CURSOR_HAND`, no two-way cursor will not be shown.

3. **`autoResizingMode` can also trigger "problems"**, making it harder to adjust width. When it's set `OFF`, when you drag column edge, it may be moved, but not freely. Be sure to set the `autoResizingMode` to `JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_SUBSEQUENT_COLUMNS` or `JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_NEXT_COLUMN` to see considerable changes.
4. (half a year later when I come back to my answer, I still find it useful...)
   If you disable the `JScrollPane` containing the table, the cursor will not change neither, and not two-way cursor will be shown.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear where your fragment goes awry. The minimal, compete example below shows a table whose columns can be resized but not reordered. In particular, note that `tbResumen` is displayed in a `JScrollPane`.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;

/**
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/38524632/230513
 */
public class Test {

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JTable tbResumen = new JTable();
        tbResumen.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
        tbResumen.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        tbResumen.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][]{
            {"label1", "label2", "label3", "label4"}},
            new String[]{"foo", "bar", "foobar", "barfoo"}));
        JTableHeader headerResumen = tbResumen.getTableHeader();
        headerResumen.setReorderingAllowed(false);

        f.add(new JScrollPane(tbResumen));
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Test()::display);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however I found something else. Will put it beneath.