# How can I make flush JButtons in swing?

Tags: java, swing, layout

I am doing a layout, and I have a pair of buttons that I would like to be flush together. I can think of a couple ways to accomplish this, but I am wondering if there is a good way.

Here is some template code:

```
package helloworld;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
/**
 * Created by matt on 22/07/16.
 */
public class FlushButtons {

    private void showGui(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton plus = new JButton("+");
        JButton minus = new JButton("-");

        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        panel.add(plus);
        panel.add(minus);

        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){

        EventQueue.invokeLater(()->{
            new FlushButtons().showGui();
        });

    }
}
```

That produces the image on the left, but I would like it to look more like the image on the right.[image: default layout] [image: desired layout]

I tried using `JButton#setMargin`, but that did not have any effect. I have used `JButton#setPreferredSize` which I can get the desired result, but I need to know the size of the button beforehand.

Comment: You could try a flow layout instead of a box layout. To be honest, most of the built-in layout managers aren't easy to use and combine, so you might want to have a look into one of the 3rd party layout managers, e.g. [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/).

Comment: @Thomas I don't think it is the layout manager, it is more of the buttons themselves. When I set the preferred size they pack ok. I just need to know the dimensions before hand.

Comment: I was trying out on my pc and your code gives me that, on Windows (so it is ugly) : https://puu.sh/qalTs/b42c6158f6.png
Seems good this way no ?

Comment: @Kapcash yes, that is good. I suppose it has to do with the UI theme. I would prefer not to switch my whole ui theme for a pair of buttons. Maybe, I should create an icon and use that.

Comment: It would solve the problem using label and icon but it is not the easiest and maintanable way :/
Did you try using the three dimension methods on the buttons (I mean min, max and pref) ? Often, Java swing needs at least two of them to do something...

Comment: @Kapcash the setPreferred is enough to resize the buttons.

Comment: Insets between JComponents are part of L&F, e.g. by using Metal L&F there is gap in one pixel(isn't required to override something), by using Windows L&F is there 4pixels, Nimbus returns 6pixels,

Comment: @mKorbel when I check the default value, the insets are 2, 0, 2, 0.

Comment: @matt 1. to try to change L&F, 2. value from Insets is valid after JFrame is already visible on the screen, 3. e.g. (without override something) Metal returns 1pixel, Windows returns 4pixels, Nimbus 6pixels, but this value is valid just for Text or Icon or text + icon inside JButton, 4. to avoids missunderstanding a) are you talking about margin inside JButton or gap between JComponents placed in container

Comment: Consider custom icons without text, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38524632/230513).

Comment: @mKorbel I don't want to change the look and feel of the whole application. As for the value of insets, this is could be what is going wrong. I think margin + (pref/min/max) size the problem is over constrained so I am doing something wrong. I am more concerned about the margins inside of the JButton at this point. The space would be more of a layout I am guessing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my solution which looks ..pretty neat!

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class FlushButtons {

    private JComponent ui = null;

    FlushButtons() {
        initUI();
    }

    private JButton getFlushButton(String text) {
        JButton b = new JButton();

        b.setBorderPainted(false);
        b.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        b.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));
        b.setBorder(null);
        b.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getImageOfText(text, Color.GREEN.darker())));
        b.setRolloverIcon(new ImageIcon(getImageOfText(text, Color.ORANGE)));
        b.setPressedIcon(new ImageIcon(getImageOfText(text, Color.RED)));

        return b;
    }

    private BufferedImage getImageOfText(String text, Color color) {
        int s = 24;
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(s, s, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();

        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, s, s);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 16));
        // use better ways to position text..
        g.drawString(text, 8, 16);

        g.dispose();
        return bi;
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui!=null) return;

        ui = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4,4,4,4));

        ui.add(getFlushButton("+"));
        ui.add(getFlushButton("-"));
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                FlushButtons o = new FlushButtons();

                JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, which looks a bit ridiculous.

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    JButton plus = new JButton("+");
    JButton minus = new JButton("-");

    plus.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(29, 29));
    plus.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(33, 33));
    minus.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(29, 29));
    minus.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(33, 33));


    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

    panel.add(plus);
    panel.add(minus);
    panel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(33));
    panel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
```

Without the vertical strut the buttons get packed without borders.

Something of a hack, hope to hear something better.